# Why won't the html5 download work in my Meteor project?

Tags: html, meteor, download, iron-router

I'm simply trying to download a file on link click like seen here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download or shown here:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

But it's not working in my Meteor project.  I'm getting redirected, but nothing downloads.  This works:

```
Template.series72.onRendered(function(){
$('.download').attr({target: '_blank', 
                    href  : '../pdfs/sizing-diagram-series-72.pdf'});
});
```

But I'm interested why the former won't.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't have experience with Meteor so I might be missing something, but it appears to me as though your forgetting to add the `download` attribute in the onRendered function. Try:

```
Template.series72.onRendered(function(){
   $('.download').attr({
        download: '',
        target: '_blank', 
        href  : '../pdfs/sizing-diagram-series-72.pdf'
   });
});
```